# Cannot convert source type to target type List<KeyValuePair> Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that is a `List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>` that returns a list; however, I'm getting an error:

> Cannot convert source type `System.Collections.Generic.List<{Key:int,
>   Value:string}>` to target type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<'int,string'>>`.

I am trying to make a Linq select statement into a new list but I don't understand if the initialized list is the problem or if its how I'm getting the values in the Linq statement.

Here is the method:

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<int,string>> GetStatus(int status)
{
   List<KeyValuePair<int,string>> st = SelectList.GetStatuses();
   List<KeyValuePair<int,string>> tp;

   switch(status)
   {
      case (int)Status.Completed:
          tp = st.Where(s => s.Key == (int)Status.Completed ||
                             s.Key == (int)Status.NotValid)
                 .Select(s => new { s.Key, s.Value }).ToList();
      case (int)Status.Open:
          tp = st.Where(s => s.Key == (int)Status.Open ||
                             s.Key == (int)Status.Reviewed)
                 .Select(s => new { s.Key, s.Value }).ToList();
      default:
          break;
   }
   return tp;
}
```

Here's the method that fills the list:

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetStatuses()
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            var sql = @"SELECT ID [Key], Text [Value] from Statuses";

            return (con.Query<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(sql.ToString(), commandType: commandType:Text) ?? Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `new { s.Key, s.Value }` you are instantiating a new anonymous type with properties `Key` and `Value`.  Instead, you probably meant to use the contructor of `KeyValuePair` by writing `new KeyValuePair(s.Key, s.Value)`.

Note, too, that your `Where` clause is already filtering a list of `KeyValuePairs`, and so no projection is even necessary.  In other words, you can drop the entire `Select` statement in this case.

So, you could use the `KeyValuePair` constructor and write:

```
tp = st.Where(s => s.Key == (int)Status.Open || s.Key == (int)Status.Reviewed)
       .Select(kvp => new KeyValuePair(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)).ToList();
```

Or, even better, simply drop the `Select` statement:

```
tp = st.Where(s => s.Key == (int)Status.Open || s.Key == (int)Status.Reviewed).ToList();
```

A little bit more on anonymous types:  Anonymous types are a C# features that allow you to make quick ad-hoc classes with custom properties.  They are especially useful with `Linq` queries.    When your program compiles, a new anonymous type is emitted with 2 properties named `Key` and `Value`.  You can thing of this a new class, without a name, that has exactly 2 properties (there are some other differences between full-fledged classes and anonymous types, but this is a convenient way to think about it).  Your method is expected to return a list of `KeyValuePairs`, but you have provided a list of objects of this new type.   Read more about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

As a general minor note, you do not need to declare the `tp` variable at all.  Instead you can `return` within your `switch` statement:

Comment: His return type is a List, so ToList is necessary btw

Comment: I was not aware I could drop the select part entirely but that certainly does make it efficient and easy to read. Thanks Ben, Sergey, Justin!

Answer (score 4):

As others have already pointed out, you are creating a new anonymous type in your `Select`, not a `KeyValuePair`. However, you are already working against a `KeyValuePair`, so you do not even need the `Select`

```
tp = st.Where(...where...).ToList();
```

There is really no point to re-instantiating the objects in the `Select` (unless you want a new reference...but KVP is immutable in this case). The `Where.ToList` is more expressive simply because it is less to grok, at least IMHO

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign list of anonymous objects `{ Key, Value }` to variable which has type of `KeyValuePair<int,string>`. If you want to reuse same `KeyValuePair` instance as returned by `GetStatuses()` call then simply remove your `Select` projection. Otherwise project each key value pair to new instance of `KeyValuePair<int,string>` type (uncomment lines below):

```
switch(status)
{
    case (int)Status.Completed:
         tp = st.Where(s => s.Key == (int)Status.Completed || s.Key == (int)Status.NotValid)  
                //.Select(s => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(s.Key, s.Value))
                .ToList();
         break; // also make sure you have break here
     case (int)Status.Open:
          tp = st.Where(s => s.Key == (int)Status.Open || s.Key == (int)Status.Reviewed)
                 //.Select(s => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(s.Key, s.Value))
                 .ToList();
         break;
}
```